# Why does Chrome not link to a stylesheet on localhost, but FireFox does?

Tags: css, google-chrome, nginx, firefox, localhost

I am using docker to run a simple webserver using nginx and php and bind-mounting the container to http://localhost:80.

**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <title>Test Application</title>
  <base href="http://localhost">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="be-stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id='contentText'>TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**be-stylesheet.css**

```
#contentText {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Chrome pulls the css file from the server just fine. However, Chrome does not appear to **use** the styles within the file when running on localhost. [Example picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVQBc.png)

[Firefox however has no issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BffXV.png)

I am able to work around this by hosting the css files externally, but for local development purposes that would not be ideal.

What is Chrome doing to block the styles from applying? Is this some kind of security feature?

Comment: Clear the cache?

Comment: @PanwenWang I wish it was simply that lol - cache is disabled

Comment: What happens if you try to inspect that stylesheet? Are you able to open it in new tab/window?

Comment: @PanwenWang Yes I am able to open/view the file via http://localhost/be-stylehseet.css just fine. It's odd. Chrome can retrieve the file but it does not apply the styles.

Comment: What do you see in Network tab of devtools when you are loading the page, for that stylesheet? I mean MIME type.

Comment: both the request and response are text/css [see here](https://imgur.com/a/dlI7ndX)